# NSURLConnection and pointer types bug

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsurlconnection

Here the problem, i'am using a http request, but when i use NSURLConnection to get my xml file and set a NSString *xml variable with that xml file i get a block pointer error if i return it. But if i take NSString *xml and send it to a method it tells me nothing and the xml variable is well set. Also if i return at the end of my method the variable, i get a nil at the parent calling method. How can i fix this because the return of the variable is needed. Thanks for any help, and here is my code :
The error :

```
incompatible block pointer types sending 'NSString *(^)NSURLResponse *, NSData *, NSError *)'to parameter of type 'void(^)(NSURLResponse *,NSData *, NSError *)' 

- (NSString *)restTestRequester: (NSString *)uriRequested serviceUri:(NSString *)sUri parameters:(NSString *)uriParameters technique:(NSString *)requestTechnique  {

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *l_api_key = [prefs stringForKey:@"globalPublicK"];
    NSString *l_secret_key = [prefs stringForKey:@"globalSecretK"];

    l_uri = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", uriRequested, sUri];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:l_uri]
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                        timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:requestTechnique];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-unrlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest setValue:l_api_key forHTTPHeaderField: @"EMApikey"];
    [theRequest setValue:[self hmacsha1:l_uri secret:l_secret_key] forHTTPHeaderField: @"EMRequestHash"];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {

         [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
       incompatible block pointer types error-->   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
         {
     here ---->xml = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                              autorelease];
         works--->[self myMethod:xml];
         doesn't work---> return(xml);
         }
         ];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }

    [theConnection release];
    equals nil variable returned-->return xml;
}
```

Comment: You're not using ARC?

Comment: No Arc, why is it the source of the problem ?

Comment: I believe the xml variable is not retaining properly create the instance variable with setter and getter and check??

Comment: It's not a retention problem. It's an asynchronous programming problem. I've posted an answer to address them. I mention ARC because if you are making this type of errors in your code, you probably do not have a full grasp of memory management concepts and ARC would greatly simplify your life.

Comment: you guessed right i don't have full aknoledgement in memory management concepts, i will switch to ARC if this help me .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that the problem is in async call, U still don't have anything in xml when U trie to return it, your method returns before sendAsynchronousRequest finishes.

USE:

```
NSData* data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString* xml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It will wait until U get the result back.

Answer (score -1):

You have several major problems. For starters, your block executes after your connection finishes. The code after the block executes after the connection *STARTS*. This means you releasing the connection before it finishes.

Additionally, you are creating `NSURLConnection *theConnection`, but never using it. When you call `-sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` it creates a completely new handler.

The specific error you are getting is because you cannot return a value from the block. The fact that you are trying indicates that you do not have a full grasp of exactly what is happening. There are many good references around the Internet about blocks and asynchronous programming. I suggest you find one.

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:l_uri];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:targetUrl                                              
                                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

[theRequest setHTTPMethod:requestTechnique];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-unrlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setValue:l_api_key forHTTPHeaderField: @"EMApikey"];
[theRequest setValue:[self hmacsha1:l_uri secret:l_secret_key] forHTTPHeaderField: @"EMRequestHash"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        // Here the connection is complete and the data is usable.
        NSString *xml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [self myMethod:xml];
        [xml release];
     }];
// Here the Connection has only been queued and no data is available.
```